# Oracle LISTAGG sum count by date and location

Tags: oracle, date, sum, listagg

I am running Oracle 12.1 on Windows.
I need help creating a list aggregate by date (entire day is the day condition, trunc(date)) and location and counting the amount of inventory type for that day in the list result.  I plan on making this a view of the car_equipment table to show the list aggregate.
I have made a simple view before showing the list of inventory for a max(date).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE NONEDITIONABLE VIEW "DB1"."CAR_INVENTORY_VW" ("MAX_INVENTORY_DATE","LOCATION", "INVENTORY_LIST") AS 
 SELECT 
  inventory_date max_inventory_date,
  location,
  LISTAGG(num_cars || ' ' || equipment_type, ', ') 
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY equipment_type) inventory_list
      FROM (
        SELECT c.*, RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY location ORDER BY inventory_date DESC) rn
            FROM car_equipment c
           ) x 
           WHERE rn = 1
            GROUP BY inventory_date, location;
```

but now I want to show all dates for a location and gather the sum of the count the inventory types by date per location.
Below is the code to create the table and rows:
First create the table and insert the rows for example of the data condition.

```
CREATE TABLE "CAR_EQUIPMENT" 
   ("NUM_CARS" NUMBER(10,0), 
"EQUIPMENT_TYPE" VARCHAR2(100 BYTE), 
"LOCATION" VARCHAR2(500 BYTE), 
"INVENTORY_DATE" DATE) 
SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE 
PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
   STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
   PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
   BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
   TABLESPACE "USERS" ;

INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-07 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('1', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-07 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('9', 'Jaguars', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-07 06:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('7', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-08-30 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('10','Trans Am', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-08-30 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('2','Trans Am', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-08-30 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('8', 'Rovers', 'coventry', TO_DATE('2019-09-06 18:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));
INSERT INTO "CAR_EQUIPMENT" (NUM_CARS, EQUIPMENT_TYPE, LOCATION, INVENTORY_DATE) VALUES ('4', 'Rovers', 'leamington', TO_DATE('2019-09-06 09:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'));

commit;
```

I could not find examples where I can get the sum(num_cars) within the listagg.
Also, ( and I hate to ask a follow on question here), but what would happen if the list aggregate exceeded 4000 bytes.  I read that xmlagg can be used, but what would be the best way to show the list if the results exceeded 4000 bytes.  Have you run into this problem before and how do you address that issue.  Thank you again for any advice.
Kindest regards, Gilly

I tried:

```
create or replace view TEST_LAGG(
  WITH
  TEMP AS (SELECT LOCATION,
                  trunc(INVENTORY_DATE) inventory_date,
                  EQUIPMENT_TYPE,
                  sum(NUM_CARS) sum_num_cars
           from CAR_EQUIPMENT
           group by LOCATION,
                    trunc(INVENTORY_DATE),
                    EQUIPMENT_TYPE
         )
   select LOCATION,
          INVENTORY_DATE,
          listagg(sum_num_cars ||' '|| EQUIPMENT_TYPE, ', ') within group (order by inventory_date) lagg
   from TEMP
   group by LOCATION,
        inventory_date);
```

But I get ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

Thanks to Littlefoot again, I tried:

```
create or replace view TEST_LAGG
 AS WITH
  TEMP (SELECT LOCATION,
                  trunc(INVENTORY_DATE) inventory_date,
                  EQUIPMENT_TYPE,
                  sum(NUM_CARS) sum_num_cars
           from CAR_EQUIPMENT
           group by LOCATION,
                   trunc(INVENTORY_DATE),
                    EQUIPMENT_TYPE
         )
    select LOCATION,
      INVENTORY_DATE,
      listagg(sum_num_cars ||' '|| EQUIPMENT_TYPE, ', ') within group   (order by inventory_date) lagg
 from TEMP
 group by LOCATION,
        inventory_date;
```

But I get the error:  ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
*Cause:
*Action:
Error at Line: 135 Column: 3 -- the TEMP table reference line.

Comment: Nice details. Can you please show expected output also?

Comment: DATE            LOCATION    CAR_LIST  
2019-09-07     Coventry      9 Rovers | 9 Jaguars

Comment: Column Headers are DATE LOCATION CAR_LIST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll first have to compute that sum, and then use it in listagg. Something like this:

```
SQL>     with
  2        temp as (select location, inventory_date, equipment_type, sum(num_cars) sum_num_cars
  3                 from car_equipment
  4                 group by location, inventory_date, equipment_type
  5                )
  6      select location,
  7             inventory_date,
  8             listagg(sum_num_cars ||' '|| equipment_type, ', ') within group (order by inventory_date) lagg
  9      from temp
 10      group by location,
 11               inventory_date;

LOCATION        INVENTORY_DATE      LAGG
--------------- ------------------- ------------------------------
coventry        2019-09-06 18:00:00 8 Rovers
coventry        2019-09-07 06:00:00 9 Jaguars
coventry        2019-09-07 09:00:00 8 Rovers
coventry        2019-09-07 18:00:00 1 Rovers
leamington      2019-08-30 00:00:00 7 Rovers
leamington      2019-08-30 09:00:00 10 Trans Am
leamington      2019-08-30 18:00:00 2 Trans Am
leamington      2019-09-06 09:00:00 4 Rovers

8 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now, it depends on what exactly you want to get as a result.

As for your second question: yes, that's XMLAGG you'll have to use if the result exceeds limit of 4000 characters.

---

### Edit

Aha; it seems that it is `TRUNC(inventory_date)` you need. It'll remove time component from date columns.

```
SQL> with
  2    temp as (select location,
  3                    trunc(inventory_date) inventory_date,
  4                    equipment_type,
  5                    sum(num_cars) sum_num_cars
  6             from car_equipment
  7             group by location,
  8                      trunc(inventory_date),
  9                      equipment_type
 10            )
 11  select location,
 12         inventory_date,
 13         listagg(sum_num_cars ||' '|| equipment_type, ', ') within group (order by inventory_date) lagg
 14  from temp
 15  group by location,
 16           inventory_date;

LOCATION        INVENTORY_DATE      LAGG
--------------- ------------------- ------------------------------
coventry        2019-09-06 00:00:00 8 Rovers
coventry        2019-09-07 00:00:00 9 Jaguars, 9 Rovers
leamington      2019-08-30 00:00:00 12 Trans Am, 7 Rovers
leamington      2019-09-06 00:00:00 4 Rovers

SQL>
```

### Edit: create a view

```
SQL> create or replace view TEST_LAGG as
  2    WITH
  3    TEMP AS (SELECT LOCATION,
  4                    trunc(INVENTORY_DATE) inventory_date,
  5                    EQUIPMENT_TYPE,
  6                    sum(NUM_CARS) sum_num_cars
  7             from CAR_EQUIPMENT
  8             group by LOCATION,
  9                      trunc(INVENTORY_DATE),
 10                      EQUIPMENT_TYPE
 11           )
 12     select LOCATION,
 13            INVENTORY_DATE,
 14            listagg(sum_num_cars ||' '|| EQUIPMENT_TYPE, ', ') within group (order by inventory_date) lagg
 15     from TEMP
 16     group by LOCATION,
 17          inventory_date;

View created.

SQL> select * from test_lagg;

LOCATION        INVENTORY_DATE      LAGG
--------------- ------------------- ------------------------------
coventry        2019-09-06 00:00:00 8 Rovers
coventry        2019-09-07 00:00:00 9 Jaguars, 9 Rovers
leamington      2019-08-30 00:00:00 12 Trans Am, 7 Rovers
leamington      2019-09-06 00:00:00 4 Rovers

SQL>
```

Comment: Hello Littlefoot, thank you for the advice, I was trying to get the sum of the inventory cars in the lagg

Comment: Also, would the standard configuration (sql) work with XMLAGG?

Comment: You're welcome. What is a "standard configuration"? XMLAGG works in SQL, if that's the question (i.e. you don't need PL/SQL for it).

Comment: Before 12.1 XML support could optionally not be installed. As of 12.1 XML support will always be available - if that's what you mean...

Comment: coventry        2019-09-07 09:00:00 8 Rovers
coventry        2019-09-07 18:00:00 1 Rovers   would be 9 rovers for that day, how would the view be created?

Comment: Thank you again Littlefoot, I was stuck on getting the (example) 9 Rovers for coventry on 2019-09-07.  How can this sum be calculated for a view of the table.  I could not figure out how to add up the types of cars on the day per location (24 hours) and output that into the listagg list. I hope that is not as confusing as it sounds...many thanks again for the assistance.

Comment: If I understood you correctly, `trunc(inventory_date)` might help as it'll remove time component from date column. I edited my message; have a look, please.

Comment: I get an error ORA-00903: invalid table name
00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"

Comment: I don't (obviously ...). I noticed you used double quotes when naming table and columns - don't do that in Oracle. Type any kind of letters you want (upper, lower, mixed case), Oracle will default them to uppercase in its internal tables and you can reference them anyway you want. But, if you use double quotes and lower/mixed case, you'll have to use double quotes ALWAYS. Is that the case when you tried it?

Comment: I can't see it, sorry. You should add it by editing the original message you posted.

Comment: Thanks again Littlefoot, I have just added the response.  So should I re-create the table without the "" to fix the issue????

Comment: Letter case is OK (as you used upper case within double quotes). Problem is: remove brackets, add AS keyword, i.e. `create or replace view test_lagg as with temp ...`

Comment: Sorry for the trouble, I posted the error and code again

Comment: I edited my answer and added CREATE VIEW statement. Have a look.

Comment: Now I am getting QL Error: ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
00928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword" after cutting and pasting your code...it is really crazy.  I can see that your code is correct.  I will have to say that your code looks perfect

Comment: Which Oracle database version do you use?